# Generic curried map function

Tags: swift, function-composition

I try to write `map` function as curried and flipped. (First transform function then collection). I did write function and compiler accepted it. But I am unable to call it. Compiler gives there is no `map` func with supplied arguments. Anyway here is the function that I wrote:

```
func map <A: CollectionType, B> (f: (A.Generator.Element) -> B) -> A -> [B] {
    return { map($0, f) }
}
```

And this is the test code:

```
func square(a: Int) -> Int {
    return a * a
}

map(square)
```

Note: Code is written inside playground with Xcode 6.3 beta 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `map` is not locked-down enough – what kind of collection is `A`?  You can’t write a generic function that generates a generic function – when you call it, the types of all the placeholders have to be fully determined.

This means you can call your `map` function, as defined, so long as you fully specify the types of `A` and `B`:

```
// fixes A to be an Array of Ints, and B to be an Int
let squarer: [Int]->[Int] = map(square)

squarer([1,2,3])  // returns [1,4,9]

// fixes A to be a Slice of UInts, and B to be a Double
let halver: Slice<UInt>->[Double] = map { Double($0)/2.0 }

halver([1,2,3])   // returns [0.5, 1, 1.5]
```

Comment: So basically type inference couldn't guess what the types should be ?

Comment: What type do you think should be inferred for `A`?  Type inference only goes so far, it needs to be based on context.  There is insufficient context for `A` in your example - it could be an array, a slice, a dictionary, any kind of collection.

Comment: OK. You are right. But if I have to do explicit type casting then there is no point to write this function so generic, right ?

Comment: It can still be useful – context can come in many forms.  Suppose you had pipe forward (`|>`) defined, and you wanted your function to sit in a pipeline i.e. `source() |> map(double) |> sink`.  The `source` function could produce any kind of collection and accept an array of any kind of type and your `map` would work with them.